# Getting scope of function caller

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a function that breaks somewhere in Line 1433 of ExtJS.

```
var createDelayed = function(h, o, scope){
console.log(arguments); //logs undefined all round. 
    return function(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        setTimeout(function(){
            h.apply(scope, args);
        }, o.delay || 10);
    };
};
```

Is there any way to see what line a function is executed from, from within itself?

(since it's a third party lib, and I cant really do

```
var me =this;
```

and log `me`)

Comment: Firebug. Breakpoint. Stack trace. That is all.

Comment: For some fun reason firebug wasn't interested in giving me a stack trace.

Comment: well, since it was breaking on the returned function, I assume thats what they call an "anonymous" function :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is `arguments.callee.caller`, which refers to the function that called the function in which you access that property. `arguments.callee` is the function itself.

There is no way to get the scope of the original function without passing it. In the following example, you cannot determine the `this` value inside `foo` (apart from knowing there is nothing special happening with `this` here):

```
function foo() {
    bar();
}

function bar() {
    console.log(arguments.callee);        // bar function
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller); // foo function
}

foo();
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments#Properties)

---

To get the line number things becomes trickier, but you can throw an error and look at the stack trace: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/6C47r/.

```
function foo() {
    bar();
}

function bar() {
    try { throw new Error; }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
}

foo();
```

For the fiddle, it logs something similar to the following in Chrome, where the end of the line says the line number and character position:

```
Error
    at bar (http://fiddle.jshell.net/pimvdb/6C47r/show/:23:17)
    at foo (http://fiddle.jshell.net/pimvdb/6C47r/show/:19:5)
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/pimvdb/6C47r/show/:29:1
```

Comment: I know this is old, but do note that the `caller` property is now obsolete.

Comment: One may use [Function.caller](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_function_caller) instead of `arguments.callee.caller`.