# Google Chrome - Watch when javascript object property changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a JavaScript variable called

```
var someProperty;
```

on line, let's say 10000 (its a huge js file), I have a function

```
function updateTime() {
     console.log(someProperty.time); //i actually get an value here
}
```

I want to find out the function that is changing the value of the property I tried setting breakpoint using Chrome dev tools directly on that var `someProperty` but received a value of "undefined" - which makes me believe a function is setting this variable.  How can I find out or watch where this `someProperty.time` property is being set?

Comment: did you try arguments.callee.name in the setter?

Comment: Won't a search for `someProperty.time=` suffice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444399/getting-scope-of-function-caller

Comment: @E.Sundin I tried that but couldn't find any matches

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution

```js
var someProp = {
  time: 'give me'
};

Object.defineProperty(someProp, 'time', {
  set: function(time) {
    this.__time = time
    console.log('Method1: Getting time from:',arguments.callee.caller)
  },
  get: function() {
    return this.__time;
  }
});

(function ILikeChanges() {
  someProp.time = 'changes';
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another modern solution would be to use a `Proxy` object to wrap your object, that will give you the ability to add listeners to updates to your object.

In the `set` function we are using `console.trace` to print a full stack trace which will direct you to the calling function.

[MDN Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```js
const watchObject = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
  set(target, key, value) {
    console.trace('set', { key, value })
    return target[key] = value
  }
});
// wrap the object with our proxy
const someProperty = watchObject({ time: new Date })

function setTime() {
  someProperty.time = new Date
}
// call the function that changes the state
setTime()
// look in your console for the call stack
```

Comment: I tried a proxy approach with the `arguments.callee.caller` method but that was not allowed. This solution is really cool!

Comment: Yeah `arguments.callee` is discouraged due to security concerns and will not work in strict mode. `Proxy` isn't available in IE unfortunately so it would need the Proxy shim to work.

Comment: But if some unknown code is changing the property, how would you tell it to use the proxy?

Comment: @torazaburo Just replace the object `someProperty = someObject` and make sure it has all the previous fields.

Comment: I think `set` should always return `true`.

Comment: @torazaburo you can return any value from the setter function.

Comment: @torazaburo you can wrap your existing object with the `watchObject` function to decorate it with the proxy. You will not have to change any other line of code. I have updated the answer. I just thought `someProperty` was a bad name and `someObject` was more descriptive.