# Is there a way to get the scopes of a function from outside the function - JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

While using chrome devtools console on a web page, searching for how I would access local variables from within a function, I realized that you can view scopes when manually inspecting a function in an object.

I accessed the function with `getEventListeners(window).load[2]` which returned

`▼{listener: ƒ, useCapture: false, passive: false, once: false, type: "load"}`

   `►listener: ƒ ()
    once: false
    passive: false
    type: "load"
    useCapture: false
   ►__proto__: Object`

when I clicked on the listener function, it showed an object
`►[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]`

The scopes object gave a list of all the variables that were used in the function (which was what I was looking for). However, I can only access these manually. There is nothing like `getEventListeners(window).load[2].listener.Scopes`

Is there any sort of function or method that will return these variables automatically. Such as:

`var foo = getEventListeners(window).load[2].listener.Scopes[0]`

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444399/getting-scope-of-function-caller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is not possible, because may represent a security problem for Javascript

And if that is not the case, maybe the variables that you´re looking for were deleted by the garbage collector at the moment when you try to get those

You can read more about Memory Management here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any sort of function or method that will return these variables automatically.

No, it's not possible. EnvironmentRecords are not accessible in "userland" code. The association between a function and an environment is internal to the function and the specification doesn't define any way to access that information.

But of course the association exists and so the developer tools can expose that information for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you would have to use

`var foo = getEventListeners(window).load[2].listener['[[Scopes]]']`

because you forgot the extra square brackets, and secondly, they aren't actually available for your JavaScript, only for devTools.

there is also a fake `[[FunctionLocation]]` that isn't available either